# libgdx check model is clicked

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using libgdx for easy 3D game, I need check model is clicked.
It is my code:

```
public int getObject (int screenX, int screenY) {   
    Ray ray = cam.getPickRay(screenX, screenY);

    int result = -1;
    float distance = -1;    

    for (int i = 0; i < rooms.size; ++i) {  
        final GameObject instance = rooms.get(i);               
        instance.transform.getTranslation(position);
        position.add(instance.center);
        final float len = ray.direction.dot(position.x-ray.origin.x, position.y-ray.origin.y, position.z-ray.origin.z);

        if (len < 0f)
            continue;

        float dist2 = position.dst2(ray.origin.x+ray.direction.x*len, ray.origin.y+ray.direction.y*len, ray.origin.z+ray.direction.z*len);

        if (distance >= 0f && dist2 > distance) 
            continue;

        if (dist2 <= instance.radius * instance.radius ) {      
            result = i;
            distance = dist2;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

It it sometimes work.

Is is my model:
http://www6.zippyshare.com/v/97501566/file.html

What do I wrong?

Any help for me?

I am new with libgdx.

[image]

When was I press 1 it lights, but when I waas press 2, 1 lights too (instead 2)...

Comment: Where does `position` come from? Is it the position of the camera?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully analyze your code nor do I know what `It it sometimes work.` actually means (e.g. in which circumstances doesn't it work?) but you're using a bounding sphere for detecting whether the object has been clicked or not.

Assuming your calculations are correct (as I said, I didn't check them in depth) you still can have false positives or negatives since the only shape which is perfectly represented by a bounding sphere is ... well... a sphere.

That might be the source for click detection to work "sometimes".

If that is the case and you want more accurate detection you should either use different bound volumes, bounding volumne hierarchies or a rendering based approach (i.e. render the object id into some buffer, which would allow for pixel perfect selection).

**UPDATE:**

From your post update it seems that bounding spheres are not the problem here, since they should not overlap, unless your data is wrong - which you should check/debug.

So the problem might actually lie in your calculations. From the documentation it looks like the ray you get is projected into the scene (i.e. into world space) so you'd need to transform your objects' center into worldspace as well.

You're currently only applying the position but ignore rotation and scale thus the resulting position might be wrong. I'm sure there's some built-in transform code, so instead of transforming manually you should use that. Please check the docs on how to do that.

Comment: I learn it with http://blog.xoppa.com/interacting-with-3d-objects/.

Have you got any sugestion how I can fix selected wrong model when clicked on screen?

Comment: @Unmerciful you might want to elaborate a bit on what `it sometimes works` actually means (maybe using a screenshot).

Comment: @Unmerciful can you debug distance, position and radius to make sure the values are correct?

Comment: Yes. Do you think I should use other method to check clicked model? Intersector (with triangles) or other method?

Comment: @Unmerciful it might help to first stick to the libgdx docs, tutorials and examples (which might be their own tests) and start from there. If it works with triangles it should work with bounding spheres as well, so if there is an example using triangles, I'd recommend using that first then switch to another method and examine the differences.